# Delete Entity With JPA

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, persistence

I couldn't delete entitys from db. I have two class one of them is receipt and other is serving. Receipt has

```
    @ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
public List<Serving> servings;
```

And i'm tring to delete a serving from a controller.

```
Serving serving = Serving.findById(servID);
serving.delete();
```

The result is;

Execution exception
PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you specify your question then? (I think I'm also going to find it interesting if Reciept is mapped in Serving and if so how?)

Comment: no no, it's only listing in receipt. so it has a relation table in db.

Comment: That you have a FK contraint in the DB -> Reciept entity needs to know about the update/delete etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
Receipt receipt = serving.getReceipt();
receipet.setServings(receipt.getServings().remove(serving));
```

Since the Receipt is the OO owner of its Servings, from an OO perspective Receipt must know when a Serving is deleted.

Maybe write a finder on Receipt for either a Serving or a servingId.

(Are you sure Servings shouldn't know about which Receipt it belongs to? - the orphanRemoval seems to indicate that a Serving really belongs to one and only one Receipt)

Comment: how can i get servings receipt? i do not keep anything about receipt in serving.

Comment: (Unless redesigning the mappings is an option, via a find query on Reciept like findByServingId()) How did you get the ID from the beginning of the Serving? And why is there an FK contraint in the DB?

Comment: JPA automaticly did it as FK constraint. But i found a way to get receipt and now i can delete servings. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the rest of the stack trace, and you should find the name of the constraint that has been violated. You probably have some other entity referencing the serving you try to delete (i.e. some other row having a foreign key to the serving row you try to delete).

So, to be able to delete this entity, you must make sure that all entities referencing it through a foreign key don't reference it anymore. How to do that depends on which entities these are, how their relation with Serving is implemented, and what you want to do: just remove the association, or delete the referencing entity as well.

Comment: I know it's a froeign key in a relation table, but it's not the answer... How can i delete this entity? :)